# iTunes Home Sharing

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, ipod, home-sharing

I want to transfer my entire iTunes library from old laptop to my new laptop.

I want to use Home Sharing for the same..Since the data is almost about 15 GB, I would like to use Home Sharing over a local network (and not through internet). I have a Wireless router.

I already tried doing a copy through iTunes Media folder (and Consolidate), but for some reasons, it does not copy all the songs..So I am trying Home Share..

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link from apple:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527

I think the section on transferring your music library via an external drive is what you're looking for, with appropriate substitutions given that you're looking to transfer over a network.